# Mp4 playback in XNA using DirectShow.Net

Tags: c#, xna, directshow, directshow.net

I am new to DirectShow and I have been trying to get MP4 playback to work properly in XNA. I am using [DirectShow.Net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) to build my graph and use a modified version of [this video playback control](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/projectusat/game/trunk/XWrapper/Graphics/Video/VideoPlayer.cs) to render the videos. This works great when using wmv and avi files (I had to modify the VideoPlayer control to use ABGR instead of ARGB (through a pixelshader), and set subType to MediaSubType.RGB32 so I didn't have to add the alpha byte).

However, when running this video player for an mp4 file (using subtype of AVC1 and using VideoInfoHeader2 for header info), I get compressed data coming into BufferCB instead.

What kind of data is coming into BufferCB and how do I render the data?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the Video Playback support already in XNA? [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.videoplayer(XNAGameStudio.41).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.videoplayer%28XNAGameStudio.41%29.aspx)